# Best place to store JavaScript variable to be easily accessible from Nightwatch tests?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I'm writing a javascript library and when some event happens I would like to store a JSON variable that can be accessed from NightwatchJs tests to validate the data that the event generated.

I used to store it as a global variable (ex. 
`window.debugLog = { message: "something", timestamp: 1111, eventType: "click", other: "stuff" };` )

and retrieve it in nightwatch with

```
browser.execute("return window.debugLog;", [], function(result){ debugLog = result.value;})
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem reliable with every browser/device when I run Nightwatch tests over Browserstack. It's not rare to have false positives because Appium failed to execute the Js function.

I was wondering if anyone has suggestions about more reliable alternatives. A cookie? A metatag? An hidden tag?

Comment: Can you access the `localStorage` in the browser ? I can't recall with nightwatch, but it's compatibility should be higher ?\

Comment: to access the localStorage you still need to execute a javascript function to read it, so I'm afraid that if the problem is with some driver failing to inject JS this won't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a file, require that file for the later tests that use it.

I have, in the custom_commands folder, a file called helperFunctions.js, and within that, this is one of the more useful functions/methods:

```
saveToFile : function(client, path, data) {
    this.fs = fs;

    buffer = new Buffer(data);
    fs.open(path, 'w', function(err, fd) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'error opening file: ' + err;
        }

        fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err) {
            if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
             return fs.close(fd, function() {
                console.log('File write: ' +  path + ' has been updated.' );
            })
        });
    })
},
```

In that way it can be called to write data from within any test:

```
this.helperFunctions.saveToFile(client, "conf/usefulVariable.js", "module.exports = {\"default\" : {},\"test_env\" : { myGlobal: " + someGlobal + "}};")
```

In the test file that needs to use it:

```
var usefulVar = require("../conf/usefulVariable.js");
```

You may need/want to JSON.stringify or parse as appropriate.